# Error in Postman 500 Internal server error post method

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, next.js, postman

It's my first time using Next Js, Mongo DB and Postman. I am building an app and when sending the information I get a 500 error in postman.
[image]
In VSC all is ok and the console does not have any errors
[image]
Can you guide me with some ideas to fix it?

I hope that the information is sent correctly and that it gives me a 201 code. As in the screenshot of the tutorial

Link to tutorial:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z-hACIsjv4E&t=3115s

I'am using mongoose to...
import mongoose from "mongoose";

```
const MONGO_URL = process.env.MONGO_URL;
console.log(process.env.MONGO_URL);


if (!MONGO_URL) {
  throw new Error(
    "Please define the MONGO_URL environment variable inside .env.local"
  );
}

let cached = global.mongoose;

if (!cached) {
  cached = global.mongoose = { conn: null, promise: null };
}

async function dbConnect() {
  if (cached.conn) {
    return cached.conn;
  }

  if (!cached.promise) {
    const opts = {
      bufferCommands: false,
    };

    cached.promise = mongoose.connect(MONGO_URL, opts).then((mongoose) => {
      return mongoose;
    });
  }
  cached.conn = await cached.promise;
  return cached.conn;
}

export default dbConnect;


import dbConnect from "../../../util/mongo";
import Product from "../../../models/Product";

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  const { method } = req;

  dbConnect();

  if (method === "GET") {
    try {
    } catch (err) {}
  }

  if (method === "POST") {
    try {
      const product = await Product.create(req.body);
      req.status(201).json(product);
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(500).json(err);
    }
  }
}

import mongoose from "mongoose";

const OrderSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    customer: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      maxlength: 60,
    },
    address: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      maxlength: 200,
    },
    total: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
    },
    status: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
    },
    method: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

export default mongoose.models.Order || mongoose.model("Order", OrderSchema);
```

Comment: are you using mongoose? can you post an example of your `POST` request?

Comment: Yes, I am using mongoose. I just uploaded the code. Thanks for noticing.